# Enum array with string name

Tags: c#, razor, enums, asp.net-core-mvc

Hello i have an Enum array in a list of checkbox (for multi select items) .
i would like to display a string base name for the checkbox label.
 haw ever i unable to display the string switch in my view 
code :

```cs
    public enum ServiceArea
    {
        // [Description("Not Completed")]
        AllOver,
        North,
        south,
        Center,
        Sharon,
    }
    public class SupplayerViewModel
    {
      ....

        public ServiceArea [] serviceArea { get; set; }
        public ServiceArea  servArae { get; set; }
        public string EnumfriendlyName => servArae.GetUserEnumName();
    }
    public static class EnumfriendlyName
    {
        public static string GetUserEnumName(this ServiceArea serviceArea)
        {
            switch (serviceArea)
            {
                case ServiceArea.AllOver: return "All Over ";
                case ServiceArea.Center:return "cc ccc";
                case ServiceArea.North:return "n n n";
                case ServiceArea.Sharon:return "sh sh";
                case ServiceArea.south:return "ss s";
            }

            return "Failure!!";
        }
    }
    public class Supplayer
    {
     ...
        public  ServiceArea [] serviceArea { get; set; }

       ...
    }
```

My razor view :

```
 @foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ServiceArea)))
                {
                    <label>
                        <i class="fas fa-street-view"></i> @item
                        <input type="checkbox" value="@item" name="ServiceArea" />
                    </label>
                }
```

Comment: You are writing out the enum, you just need to call your method, for example, something like this: `@((ServiceArea)item).GetUserEnumName()`

Comment: true, and logical ,just dont know where to call it , im get error where ever i try calling it (in the view)

Comment: Then tell us what the error is!

Comment: in this line in the foreach & in the item i have no access to GetUserEnumName

Comment: @((ServiceArea)item.GetUserEnumName()) =object' does not contain a definition for 'GetUserEnumName' and the best extension method overload 'EnumfriendlyName.GetUserEnumName(ServiceArea)' requires a receiver of type 'ServiceArea'

Comment: Well you probably need an `@import ...` line

Comment: i thought  so to but i do have @using Market.Models.Features (that where it is ) in the view & controller etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finely get it 
@EnumfriendlyName.GetUserEnumName((ServiceArea)@item)